How do I map denormalized records into one EF Entity with collections?
(I don't own this data so I can't add constraints or properly normalize it)
I have a denormalized table where I have many records with the same primary Id and those records each contain what should be a foreign key from another table. It looks like this.
CREATE TABLE DenormalizedDummy(
  Id bigint NULL,
  OtherTableId varchar(255) NULL, -- Yes, it's a varchar
  Notes varchar(255) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE OtherTable(
  Id varchar(255) NULL,
  Notes varchar(255) NULL
) 

The data ends up looking something like this:
DenormalizedDummy



Id
OtherTableId
Notes




1
One
Dummy also linked to OtherTableId "Two"


1
Two
Dummy also linked to OtherTableId "One"



OtherTable



Id
Notes




One
OtherTable linked to DenormalizedDummyId 1


Two
OtherTable linked to DenormalizedDummyId 1



I already have OtherTable mapped like this with a collection of DenormalizedDummies, like so:
public class DenormalizedDummyTypeConfiguration : 
  IEntityTypeConfiguration<DenormalizedDummy> 
  {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DenormalizedDummy> builder)
      {
        builder.ToTable("OtherTable");
        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
          .HasColumnName("Id")
           ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); 
          
         builder.HasOne(e => e.OtherTable)
          .WithMany(e => e.Dummies)
          .HasForeignKey(e => e.OtherTableId);
      }
  }

  public class DenormalizedDummy
  {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public OtherTable OtherTable { get; set; }
  }

  public class OtherTableTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<OtherTable> 
  {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OtherTable> builder)
    {
      builder.ToTable("OtherTable");
      builder.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasColumnName("Id")
        .HasMaxLength(255)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); 

      builder.HasMany(e => e.Dummies)
        .WithOne(e => e.OtherTable)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.OtherTableId);
    }
  }

  public class OtherTable
  {
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public List<DenormalizedDummy> Dummies { get;set; } = new();
  }

But I'd really like to map multiple DenormalizedDummy records into one DenormalizedDummy entity like this...
public class DenormalizedDummyTypeConfiguration : 
  IEntityTypeConfiguration<DenormalizedDummy> 
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DenormalizedDummy> builder)
  {
    builder.ToTable("OtherTable");
    builder.Property(e => e.Id)
      .HasColumnName("Id")
      .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); 
          
    builder.HasMany(e => e.OtherTables)
      .WithMany(e => e.Dummies);
  }
}

public class DenormalizedDummy
{
  [Key]
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Notes { get; set; }
  public List<OtherTable> OtherTables { get; set; } = new();
} 
    
public class OtherTableTypeConfiguration : 
  IEntityTypeConfiguration<OtherTable> 
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OtherTable> builder)
  {
    builder.ToTable("OtherTable");
    builder.Property(e => e.Id)
      .HasColumnName("Id")
      .HasMaxLength(255)
      .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); 
    
    builder.HasMany(e => e.Dummies)
      .WithMany(e => e.OtherTables);
  }
}
    
public class OtherTable
{
  [Key]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Notes { get; set; }
  public List<DenormalizedDummy> Dummies { get;set; } = new();
}

I'm really not sure how to do this, though. I feel like it should be a self-join or use table splitting, but I've never done either of those to know for sure.
Help?

I don't get it. Is "other table" an other table (what would its schema be in this case?) or does it designate other records in the same table? What does "same primary Id" mean? Primary keys must be unique! Can you show some sample data?

For which purpose you need this? Select can produce such result. Not sure that EF can allow defining such navigation property.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I've updated the question to include data and OtherTable's schema and entity declaration
It is not a typo that the schema doesn't include Primary Keys; they don't exist.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv -- I'm running into an issue where, as far as I can tell, EF only sees one DenormalizedDummy and I need to be able to link the single entity to two OtherTable entitites.

I don't think you can normalize it in the mapping configuration. You will either have to create normalizing views in the database (simulating a main table with a unique Id and a link table) and map these views or do the processing with LINQ.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes -- that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks. :)
